# issues to inspect a long text file

Tags: editor, tail

If I run

```
sudo pico /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log
```

I get a very long file, and I cannot see last lines. If I run:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log | awk '{print $1 "--"  $2}'
```

I don't get anything ? What am I doing wrong ?

Also, how can I move to a specific line using pico editor ?

thanks

Comment: Your commands work for me. How long is "very long"? (eg. how many lines? or MB or GB?) .. You have used `tail -f`, so I assume the file is growing. Is it growing very rapidly? .. and by the way, in Ubuntu `pico` is actually `nano`. To see this, run: `readlink -e $(which pico)` .. I've not used pico/nano before, but the `man` page only mentions a commandline option to open the file at a specific line,column, eg. pico +1000,7 filename ... PS.. it does take quite a while for the tail/awk combo to catch up with the new line additons  when I add **many** lines **very** fast. This may be the proplem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using nano for logfiles is not recommended as it loads the whole file into the memory. Use `less`:

```
less /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log
```

Press <kbd>F</kbd> to get the effect from `tail -f`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read only the last lines of the log use `tail -aNumber /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log`

Replacing aNumber with the number of lines you want to see.

If you want to see the whole file use `vi /var/log/lighttpd/website/error.log`
you could also use nano, it´s easier...